# Como fazer downloads pelo prompt de comando?

Tags: windows, download, prompt, wget

Já vi vários vídeos, mas não quero baixar aquele tal de `Wget`. Não existe outra maneira?

Comment: O `wget` funciona para mim perfeitamente - uso o Ubuntu. Creio que no seu caso, como usuário do Windows, teria de ser de outra forma. Relacionado: http://superuser.com/questions/59465/is-it-possible-to-download-using-the-windows-command-line

Comment: Eu acho uma dúvida válida, já que no ubuntu é tão fácil fazer isso e também não temos um Super User :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há diversas formas de resolver.

Caso queira algo similar a sistemas *nix, existe o `wget` para windows:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Para quem está habituado, não tem segredo.

```
wget http://endereço.do/arquivo/para.baixar
```

Caso queira usar recursos nativos do Windows, encontrará no PowerShell. Um exemplo simples:

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://endereço.do/arquivo/para.baixar -OutFile c:\foo.file
```

Note que dentro do PowerShell há aliases, como exemplo, `wget` é um alias para `Invoke-WebRequest`.
A linha de comando acima pode ser escrita da seguinta forma

```
wget http://endereço.do/arquivo/para.baixar -OutFile c:\foo.file
```

Apenas atente-se que o alias nada tem a ver com o `wget`, popular em plataformas linux.

Ainda no PowerShell, outro meio de fazer um download:

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile( "http://endereço.do/arquivo/para.baixar", "c:\foo.file")
```

Comment: +1 por acreditar na pergunta :)

Comment: -1 por ignorar que na pergunta o autor já estabeleceu que não quer usar `wget`,@WallaceMaxters :)

Comment: @arfneto, eu não ignorei o contexto da pergunta. Apenas expliquei que o wget pode já estar nativo como alias no sistema operacional no PowerShell... 
O autor queria evitar ter que baixar um simulador do wget do linux para windows.. Eu vi que faltou conhecimento sobre o assunto usando recursos nativos do windows e por isso respondi dessa forma.. 

Agora, injusto é negativar ignorando completamente tudo que respondi aí. Se eu tivesse respondido apenas "use o wget", daí sim, seria justo negativar..

Aliás, o próprio autor da pergunta definiu a resposta como satisfatória. 

Comment: @DanielOmine na verdade eu não "negativei" sua resposta. Era só uma ironia na expressão. Mas entendo o que disse e você tem razão.

Answer (score 3):

Parece que no link do [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/59465/is-it-possible-to-download-using-the-windows-command-line) há algumas respostas, que não são diretamente pelo CMD.

Então, vou dar minha sugestão:

## PHP

O PHP também pode ser utilizado na linha de comando. Podemos então ler um arquivo através do `readfile` e salvá-lo em um arquivos do seu computador.

Veja:

```
> php -r "readfile('http://url_do_download');" > nome_do_arquivo_baixado.ext
```

## CURL

Outra forma seria através do `bash`, que sempre é instalado no `Windows` quando você instala o `git`.
Daí você poderia utilizar o `curl` da seguinte forma:

```
> curl http://url_do_download > nome_do_arquivo.ext
```

**Observação**: Não sei se existe outra forma de instalar o `bash` no `Windows`.

Comment: Acho que as informações da resposta já estão claras o suficiente